# Mongoose/MongoDB in Node.JS stops returning records after a while

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mlab

I have a script running which finds data in a database I have. For some reason after a short period of time, it stops finding any data but does not output any errors to the screen or through node.js. Here is the following setup I have for mongoose. I have a database at MLAB btw!

```
var connectionOptions = {
    server: {
        auto_reconnect: true,
        poolSize: 16,
        socketOptions: {
            keepAlive: 120,
            connectTimeoutMS: 5 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
            socketTimeoutMS: 5 * 60 * 1000
        }
    },
    replset: {
        poolSize: 16,
        socketOptions: {
            connectTimeoutMS: 300000, // 5 minutes
            keepAlive: 120
        },
        ha: true, // Make sure the high availability checks are on
        haInterval: 5000, // Run every 10 seconds
    }
};

//mongoose.set('debug', true);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://XXXXXXXXXXXX@XXXXXX.mlab.com:57328,XXXXXXXX.mlab.com:57328/XXXXXXXXX?replicaSet=rs-XXXXXX', connectionOptions, function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
});

mongoose.connection.on('connecting', function () {
    console.log('Connecting to MongoDB...');
});

mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
    console.log('MongoDB connected!');
});

mongoose.connection.on('open', function () {
    console.log('MongoDB connection opened!');
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
    mongoose.disconnect();
});

mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {
    console.log('MongoDB disconnected!');
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://XXXXXXXXXXXX@XXXXXX.mlab.com:57328,XXXXXXXX.mlab.com:57328/XXXXXXXXX?replicaSet=rs-XXXXXX', connectionOptions, function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
    });
});

mongoose.connection.on('reconnected', function () {
    console.log('MongoDB reconnected!');
});

mongoose.connection.on('close', function () {
    console.log.error('MongoDB closed');
});

mongoose.connection.on('ha', function(type, data) {
    console.log('replset ha ' + type);
});

mongoose.connection.on('timeout', function () {
    console.log.error('MongoDB timeout');
});
```

I have seen a lot of configurations and I've tried a ton of different things but nothing seems to work.

I would really appreciate the help, as I've been researching around for quite a bit to no luck.

And to recap again, I have a script running querying records from a database, and after a certain time, the script will keep running but seem to not find any new records and stop responding to any new data.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and still can't find a way to fix it. I have a linux CRON calling an endpoint that searches for data in Mongo every 15 minutes. After a couple of hours it simply stops returning data even though I can manually execute that query on the shell and get results. I'm running crazy already.

Comment: So this happens just for cron or when you normally run the script as well?

Comment: It only happens in my node API, which is currently using the MongoDB node JS driver. The cron keeps calling an endpoint from this API. After a few hours it stops working, but I can still copy the query to a mongoDB shell and it will return what I'm expecting. As soon as I restart my API the endpoint starts working again until a few hours go by and the issue happens again. More details here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/LkJV0ARHbV8

Comment: are you deployed to heroku or something? Could this be related to a cold-start issue where it not-responding is actually the server spinning up dynamically?

Comment: Deployed on AWS EC2. Like explained in the link above everything works fine besides getting the data out of my aggregation call. The same query will return nothing after a few hours of server uptime but when copied to the Mongo shell it returns everything that I expect. If I restart the server, the query works again but after a few hours the issue shows up again.

Comment: @RodolfoPerottoni do you see any error in the `mongod` logs, or is there any error printed by the application? I assume the endpoint keeps a database connection open for ~5 hours and it's possible that it's timing out on something

Comment: @KevinAdistambha I can't check for logs because I'm using MongoDB Atlas. Yes, my endpoints share the same connection which is kept alive 24/7, but only my cron endpoints are failing after a certain period of time. I have ~100 other endpoints in the same webservice being used at the same time and they all work flawlessly.

Comment: @RodolfoPerottoni which Atlas instance are you using? Is it the free tier or the paid tier?

Comment: @KevinAdistambha it's the free tier

Comment: @RodolfoPerottoni could you take a look at [Atlas Free Tier limitations](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/free-shared-limitations/) and [Atlas Free Tier unsupported commands](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/unsupported-commands/)? Maybe your constant monitoring is hitting some free tier limits. Actually, if the cron job works if you test it using a local deployment, there's a high chance that the issue is due to some free tier limits.

Comment: @KevinAdistambha I've upgraded my server to an M10 to test it out and the issue remains. I swear I read the entire MongoDB documentation and there's nothing that explains this behavior. For the moment, I've split my aggregation into multiple **find** calls to solve my issue. I called MongoDB and the solution they gave me was to buy an Enterprise plan to get this issue analysed by an "expert". What a joke.

Comment: @RodolfoPerottoni I have posted a series of questions in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/LkJV0ARHbV8. Let's continue the conversation in that thread instead.

Comment: Is it happen on a local Mongo Db also? or only when you deploy your app?

Comment: Possibility : Looks like your query is a bit expensive. Pipeline stages in aggreagte query have a limit of 100 megabytes of RAM. You need to use allowDiskUse and set it to true to verify the issue. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/#agg-memory-restrictions

Comment: If your app is deployed on heroku's free dinos, it's put to sleep after 20 minutes, I used to face a similar problem and that was the reason.

Comment: did you ever find a solution on this problem? I think I might be facing a similar situation

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your configurations there but you can try mine:

```
  mongoose.connect(
  process.env.DB_CONNECT,
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  },
  () => {
    console.log("Connected To MongoDB");
  }
);
```

Comment: I can vouch for this, I have the same config (except I don't use useCreateIndex) and it works just fine